# Testing FormData in pure Javascript and is not responding

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am testing FormData in pure javascript. The code in Jquery works fine, but Pure Javascript does not give any results. I have checked thoroughly, seems I am overlooking some code. Any help, please?

HTML:

```
     <form id="myForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">               
                <div> <label for="fname"> First Name</label>
                     <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Enter your First Name" required> </div>
                <div> <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
                     <input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" required> </div>
                <div> 
                     <label for="email">Email </label>
                     <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="buttons" onclick="submitFormAjax()">Submit</button>
      </form>
 <div id="response_message"></div>
   <script src="stack.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
function submitFormAjax() {
    var  xmlhttp;
//Checking for Old window versions
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest){
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else if(window.ActiveXObject){
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
}
  xmlhttp.open("POST", "custstack.php", true);
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200)
    {
        document.getElementById("response_message").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
  }
// Retrieving the form data
   var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
   var formData = new FormData(myForm);
   // Sending the request to the server
   xmlhttp.send(formData);
}
```

PHP:

```
<?PHP
    $fname = clean( $_POST[ "name" ] );   echo " <br /> Name = " . $fname . "<br />";
    $lname = clean( $_POST[ "name" ] );   echo " <br /> Last Name = " . $lname . "<br />";
    $tel = clean( $_POST[ "tel" ] ); echo " <br /> Phone = " . $tel . "<br />";
    $email = clean( $_POST[ "email" ] ); echo " <br /> Email = " . $email . "<br />";
    $password = clean( $_POST[ "password" ] ); echo " <br /> Password = " . $password . "<br />";
    function clean( $userinput ) {
        $inp = trim( $userinput );
        $inp = stripslashes( $userinput );
        $inp = htmlspecialchars( $userinput );
        return $inp;
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please provide a detailed explanation of the problem. You say that it does not give any results, but when I run this code the Email shows up as expected. If you want the First Name and Last Name to be shown, you should change the PHP to `$_POST["fname"]` and `$_POST["lname"]` respectively. The Phone and Password obviously do not show as there is no HTML input for them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show the post data on the same page you don't need ajax:

```
<?php
print "<FORM id='myForm'   action='{$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']}'  method='POST' enctype='multipart/form-data'>";
?>
<div> <label for="fname"> First Name</label>
<input type="text" id="fname" name="fname" placeholder="Enter your First Name" required> </div>
<div> <label for="lname">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Enter your Last Name" required> </div>
<div> <label for="lname">Phone Number</label>
<input type="text" id="tel" name="tel" placeholder="Enter your Phone number" required> </div>
<div><label for="email">Email </label>
<input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required><div><
<label for="password">Password </label>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter your password" required>
</div>
<button type="submit" class="buttons" >Submit</button>          
<?PHP
function getPostValue($trigger){ 
$value = "";
    if(!empty($_POST[$trigger]))
    {
    $value = clean( $_POST[$trigger]);
    }  
return $value;
}

function clean( $userinput ) {
$inp = trim( $userinput );
$inp = stripslashes( $userinput );
$inp = htmlspecialchars( $userinput );
return $inp;
}

echo " <br /> Name = " . getPostValue("fname") . "<br />";
echo " <br /> Last Name = " . getPostValue("lname")  . "<br />";
echo " <br /> Last Phone = " . getPostValue("tel")  . "<br />";
echo " <br /> Email = " . getPostValue("email")  . "<br />";
echo " <br /> Password = " . getPostValue("password")  . "<br />";

?>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. I was also able to print directly with PHP, without ajax, but I was testing if it works with ajax, but your answer certainly helped me. Thanks.